# Changing color of circle mouse when moving to new section

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a little and simple js script (just starting) to make the mouse on my website a circle instead of a regular one.
I need to make it switch border color on the next website section. Is this thing to change in js or is it something is should change in HTML, css?

Here is the link for test web - https://naughty-cori-05cc08.netlify.app/

````
let navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');

window.addEventListener('mousemove',cursor);


function cursor(e) {
    mouseCursor.style.top = e.pageY + 'px';
    mouseCursor.style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
    div.style.border = white;
    
}

navLinks.forEach(link => {
    link.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
        mouseCursor.classList.remove("link-grow");
        link.classList.remove("hovered");
        });
link.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
mouseCursor.classList.add("link-grow");
link.classList.add("hovered");
});
});```
````

Comment: What is `mouseCursor`?

Comment: `let mouseCursor = document.querySelector(".cursor"); `

Comment: Also here it is div properties. This div is based in body. `.cursor {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  border: 2px solid $blue;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition-property: background, transform;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this very simply in css:

```css
cursor: url(your_image_path.png) (width) (height), (mode);
```

But for more details (and since i haven't used this property my self) go and see MDN's https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor and many other website's on this topic.
Now... if you weren't thinking of making an actual .png-.jpeg-.ani i don't know if there is way forward to do it Google it even more.